# Javascript video popup on click slider button

Tags: javascript, youtube

I am trying to run a script where ..a slider url is # and the name of slider button is "slide_8". when somebody clicks over it a youtube video pops out.
In my script below video is playing but cannot be seens anywhere on browser.
I have kept the youtube url inside the javascript.

```
<div class="overlay" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="propose-video-wrap" style="display: none;"> 
<div id="propose_video"></div> 
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#slide_8').click(function() {
    var video_htm = '<a class="pop-close-btn" onclick="closeVideoPopup();"></a> <iframe id="propose_video_iframe" width="300" height="150" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/SQtxJ15vzOU?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>';
    $('#propose_video').html(video_htm);
    $('.overlay').css('display', 'block');
    $('.propose-video-wrap').css('display', 'block');
    $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
});

function closeVideoPopup() {
    $('.overlay').css('display', 'none');
    $('.propose-video-wrap').css('display', 'none');
    $('#propose_video').html('');
    $('body').css('overflow-y', '');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I pasted this code in JSfiddle, added a button and it works. The only changes I've made is adding an event listener for clicking on the closing button, because for some reason the inline didn't work on JSfiddle, as well as inserting some text inside the closing button, so it's possible to click it.

It's possible that the issue is with your styles, for example that any of your elements has a negative z-index or is positioned in a weird way. Disable the `display: none` attribute and insert some text inside those HTML elements first and see where they end up.

If you'd like to see what I ended up with, [here is is](https://jsfiddle.net/Voreny/8cLaxujq/1/).